# JetpackCompose how to createChooser and listen for result

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show a system dialog to user to select from available applications for sharing text from my app. I can do this by using createChooser function from Intent class. But i also want to listen for the system dialog result, so that i can disable/enable my share button to prevent creating multiple system dialogs overlapping each other.

To do this i need to know whenever the dialog is dismissed or an app option is selected by the user. So i need the result of the chooser Dialog i have created.

I was able to get the selected app, but was not able to listen the dismiss event for the system dialog because *Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS* event is deprecated for third party applications. So is there any other way on how to know when the system dialog is closed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to listen the result using *rememberLauncherForActivityResult* Composable function by combining it with *ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult* abstract class. you can see the usage example i have implemented below. Please share your opinions/corrections or alternatives for my problem.

```
var shareEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        // you can use the ActivityResult(it) here
        shareEnabled = true
    }
Button(
    onClick = {
        shareEnabled = false
        launcher.launch(getShareText().shareExternal())
    },
    enabled = shareEnabled
)
```

shareExternal is an extension function that creates and returns the chooser Intent;

```
fun String.shareExternal(): Intent {
    val dataToShare = this
    val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dataToShare)
        type = "text/plain"
    }
    return Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
}
```

Comment: Does this approach still work? I tried to use this way but after selecting an app from the intent chooser the activity result is not being called even if the text was shared. When user returns back to my app, the activity result receives `resultCode=RESULT_CANCELED`

Comment: Yes, this still works, i am still using it. If you can see the app enters the result block, you are probably getting an error from OS while during the Intent.